# Feign client packaging

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign

I'm quite new to Feign. Just discover it today ...
My first question when i read about Spring Cloud Feign is : "**how do you package your feign client ?**"

I'm taking an example. 
Suppose we have 2 microservices M1 and M2.
M2 consume a endpoint from M1.

We can for example, **build 2 jars for M1** :

1. the first one will be the microservice itself.
2. the second one can be the Feign client of M1, exposing the services.

In this solution, I saw an analogy with **EJB2 stub and skeleton parts**. And I saw another possible advantage : the Feign client is always in sync (v1) with the implementation (v1).

or do you only declare the **Feign client inside the M2** microservices. That is if a third microservice need M1, it will also declare a Feign client (that can be a little different because its needs are different).

Perhaps I'm totally wrong, please correct me.

Thanks a lot !
Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea behind Feign is only getting a rest client for your Microservice, and of course, it should be in sync with the exposed service

With this info in mind:

do you only declare the Feign client inside the M2 microservices.
- Yes, your M2 should declare a dependency on it to consume the exposed service by M1

That is if a third microservice need M1, it will also declare a Feign client (that can be a little different because its needs are different).
- I don't think so, the client should be the same all the time, it could be different only if your API rest has changed, otherwise, all feign clients should be the same